# Degree Precision vs. Length

Tags: latitude-longitude, precision

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

I found this chart in one of the questions here.
Additional to this:  When making a measurement and getting 2 Measures of Latitude, for example  51.1901354 and 51.1901359.
Is it then possible to say that these points are 5.55 cm apart?
Also, I am using this formula to get meters rather then degree:

Northing = (Latitude-Base_Latitude)*(6378137*pi/180)

Easting =(Longitude-Base_Longitude)*(6378137*pi/180) * cos(Base_Latitude*pi/180)

Is the Chart above usable with this Convertion?

Comment: you should also look for Vicenty and haversine on this site. Note that 5.5 cm is very small compared to the Earth, so the difference between the types of distance will not be very large.

Comment: @ radouxju: from that thread I got the basic idea about this.  I just want to be sure that it will work with the type of convertion I am using.  Additional: If a GPS System has a accuracy of 2 cm and you get measurements as in the example above, is it then accurate to say that those measurements are not in that accuracy, or do you need longitude as well for that?

Comment: Are you asking how do you calculate the distance between two latitude and longitude coordinates?

Comment: No, that I am doing in the local coordinate system with

sqrt(x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2).

I wanted to know how accurate the chart is, in combination with the convertion I am using.